# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on a function between two topological spaces such that it satisfies the following property?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Let $(X,\tau_X)$ and $(Y,\tau_Y)$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ is a function such that for all $A,B\subseteq X$, $$f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(B)} \implies A\subseteq \overline{B}$$where $\overline{f(B)}$ denotes the closure of $f(B)$ in $f(X)$ and $\overline{B}$ denotes the closure of $B$ in $X$.

**My Questions**

1. Does there exist any standard name for these type of functions?
2. If $f$ is continuous, then what other conditions on $f$ are sufficient such that it satisfies the above property?
3. Are the conditions also necessary?

**My Attempt**

I already tried asking the question [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53414861#53414861), however, as you can see I got no response.

Comment: Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\sin(x)$. Obviously $f$ is a continuous function that maps all real numbers to $[-1,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$, but its inverse mapping is a surjection that maps $[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, this doesn't satisfy your condition. So I think $f^{-1}$ should be injective.

Comment: @KevinSong Your function $f$ has no inverse $f^{-1}:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ so it's not clear what you mean by this. Possibly that $f$ should be injective? This will certainly be the case if $X$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: @Ali I mean the map, I didn't say it's an inverse function, the OP only claimed that $f$ is a function.

Comment: So if we take $f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(B)}\subseteq[-1,1]$, we don't know the relationship between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Conversely, if $f$ is injective and in addition an open map, then the condition holds. (btw @KevinSong I still think you are talking about the injectivity of $f$)

Comment: @Ali maybe my language isn't clear.

Comment: @KevinSong: Unless I am missing something, I don't think that injectivity is necessary. Consider the zero function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ where the domain has the indiscreet topology and the codomain has the discreet topology. Then for any $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, it it trivially holds that $f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(B)}$ (since $\{0\}$ is closed). Furthermore it is also immediate that $A\subseteq \overline{B}$ because any non-empty subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (domain) is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is why I brought up the Hausdorff condition.

Comment: @Ali: Can you prove that $f$ must be injective if $X$ is Hausdorff? (You may also consider it adding as a (partial?) answer to the post if you have time.)

Comment: Suppose there exist $a\neq b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$.
  If $X$ is Hausdorff then there exist
  open neighbourhoods $\mathcal{N}_{a}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{b}$ with
  $\mathcal{N}_{a}\cap\mathcal{N}_{b}=\emptyset$.
Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\mathcal{N}_{b}$. Then $f(A)\subseteq f(B) \subseteq \overline{f(B)}$
  but $A\nsubseteq \overline{B}$. The contradiction implies $f$ injective.

Comment: @user170039 Would you like to discuss this question in a chat room?

Comment: @Ali: Just one minor remark. If I am not wrong then your proof works even if $f$ is not continuous, right?

Comment: A sufficient condition on $f$ would be that for all $B\subseteq X$, $f^{-1}(\overline{f(B)})\subseteq \overline{B}$.

Answer (score 2):

The condition
$\forall A,B\ \ (f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(B)}\Rightarrow A\subseteq \overline{B})$ is equivalent to

$$(*)\qquad\qquad \forall x, B\qquad f(x)\in \overline{f(B)}\Rightarrow x\in \overline{B}.$$

Under mild assumptions on $X,Y$ and continuity, this is equivalent to injectivity.

Easy implication:
Suppose $X$ is $T_1$. If $(*)$ holds, then from $f(x)=f(y)\in \overline{f(y)}$ you get $x\in \overline{y}=y$ (because points are closed), hence $x=y$ and thus $f$ is injective.

Trickier one:
 Suppose $f$ is continuous and injective. Suppose $X$ is compact and $Y$ Hausdorff. Then if $f(x)\in \overline B$ there is a net $(b_i)$ such that $f(b_i)\to f(x)$. Since $X$ is compact, $b_i$ sub-converges to some $b\in B$, and by continuity $f(b_i)\to f(b)$. Since $Y$ is $T_2$ then you have uniqueness of the limit so $f(b)=f(x)$. By injectivity $b=x$, so $x\in \overline B$.

If you dislike nets, you can (build a proof without them, or) work with first countable spaces and usual sequences.

I don't know if there is a general name for property $(*)$. Without compactness (but still with continuity and some separation axiom) it sounds to me as a kind of injectivity at infinity: you forbidd that $f(b_i)\to f(x)$ if $b_i$ does not converge to $x$.

Comment: This is a nice answer. But I will wait just in case someone writes a post that completely answers my question.

Comment: I think the converse part can be proved more simply under your assumptions. Since [by this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuous_Bijection_from_Compact_to_Hausdorff_is_Homeomorphism) $X$ is homeomorphic to $f(X)$. Hence $f(A)\subseteq \overline{f(B)}\implies f^{-1}(f(A))\subseteq  f^{-1}(\overline{f(B)})$. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, we have $\overline{f(B)}=f(\overline{B})$. Hence $f^{-1}(\overline{f(B)})=f^{-1}(f(\overline{B}))=\overline{B}$. Consequently we have $A\subseteq \overline{B}$.

Comment: @user170039 yes, you're right. When X is compact and Y is Hausdorff, then X is homeo to f(X).

Comment: If it's a homeomorphism then it's an open map. See my second comment above.